# In Jer. 45:4, What Jehovah is saying with "that which I have built...planted...I am throwing down...I am plucking up"?

Tags: jeremiah, attributes-of-god

Text: Jer. 45:4 (YTL)

> Thus dost thou say unto him: Thus said Jehovah: Lo, that which I have built I am throwing down, and that which I have planted I am plucking up, even the whole land itself.

Comment: God planted (established) Israel in their land and was about to have them captured by foreigners, or "uprooted".  Fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to this come from earlier in the same book of Jeremiah, in particular, Jer 18 -

> **7** At any time I might announce that a nation or kingdom will be uprooted, torn down, and destroyed. **8** But if that nation I warned
> turns from its evil, then I will relent of the disaster I had planned
> to bring.
>
> **9** And if at another time I announce that I will build up and establish a nation or kingdom, **10** and if it does evil in My sight
> and does not listen to My voice, then I will relent of the good I had
> intended for it.

The nation of Israel was clearly in the latter category - a nation that God had, via the miracles of the Exodus, established by His wisdom and might.  However, the record of their sinful, ways that rejected God as their real leader and sovereign, meant that God had to allow them to go into Babylonian captivity.

In the previous few chapters before Jer 45, Jeremiah the prophet had faithfully documented the following events:

- Jer 39 - the fall of Jerusalem to Babylon
- Jer 40 - Jeremiah set free and Gedaliah, the replacement governor assassinated
- Jer 41-43 - The remaining residents of Jerusalem confer and decide to escape to Egypt
- Jer 44 - The record of why Jerusalem had been destroyed because of idolatry

Thus, Jer 45 is written before the above events but anticipates them perfectly and predicts that Jerusalem, the very chosen nation of god, that God established, would be torn down as per V4

> Jer 45:4 - Thus shall you say to him, Thus says the LORD: Behold, what
> I have built I am breaking down, and what I have planted I am plucking
> up—that is, the whole land.

Thus, Jeremiah correctly predicted the final destruction of Jerusalem and "all the land" by the Babylonians.

Note the comments of the Cambridge commentary on Jer 45:4 -

> **Behold, that which I have built, etc.** Baruch is pained at the calamities in which his country is involved, but let him be sure that
> the Lord, in bringing Himself to overthrow His cherished people, can
> only be thus acting because no other course is possible (see introd.
> note).

Similarly, the Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary says this:

> **4. that which I have built … planted I will pluck up**—(Isa 5:5). This whole nation (the Jews) which I founded and planted with such
> extraordinary care and favor, I will overthrow.